# Detect no text changed in textbox

Tags: c#

I have make my text box to detect key press, the back color of text box will change from red to white.

Questions: How if the user delete the text they type because they type wrongly, so there will be no text changed/ input in the text box, and i need to detect this event(no user input) and changed back the text box from white to red?

Comment: Winform or wpf? Use TextChanged event instead.

Comment: `TextChanged` event is your friend here...

Comment: i am using textchanged event, but i wan this event to detect no input, means no text changed, how can i do that?

Comment: so if no text changed is detected, the backcolor of textbox wil changed

Comment: Just add if(yourTextbox.Text != "")

Comment: Solved it , thanks guys

i add line like below:

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))

Answer (score 0):

Change the back colour to Red/White on load depending on your requirement.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Then add a condition to check for bank text in the textbox as below:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.CompareTo("") != 0)
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: how do i capture the user input of my textbox?